# Using MediaPlayer in a non Activity class

Tags: android, this, android-mediaplayer, media, android-context

I am having some trouble using the android `MediaPlayer` in a non activity class, always a context error. Here is the bugged line:

```
MediaPlayer Shoot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shot);
```

Now I know I cant use "`this`" in a service, but all the other stuff I tried kept giving bugs.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too luck because in the last two days I have develop an app that uses MediaPlayer inside a background Service ;)

You can simply retrieve an instance of your MediaPlayer using the next line:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Then you can set all listener and play song that you want.

**Edit 22th april 2012**

To set listeners (an example):

```
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {                

                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        // TODO notify error to user or play next song
                        return true;
                }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {                       

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Notify to user the completion of song or play next song
                }
        });
```

To start and play song you have to do something like this:

```
try{
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mSongUrl);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
// Starting media player
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the context reference to the constructor of your non activity class.
and then from there save it and pass it to where it is needed.

Make sure your context reference no longer remain live after its use. Else it will gonna cause memory issue.

Comment: Not sure i got it, can you please give an example?